# Changing height of 'rallychart' component to fill outer container

Tags: rally, appsdk2

I have a 'rallychart' component on my page that renders with a dynamic width which fills the outer container, but who's height is fixed at 400px. I tried to use the *setSize* function of the component but it seems to change the chart container size instead of the chart itself. Is there a setting to just have the chart fill both the width and height by default, or at least a way for me to listen for a page resize event and change the height of the chart manually?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

To have a 'rallychart' component with height greater than 400px, change the *chartConfig -> chart -> height* setting to reflect the desired height.

Note: the height will be fixed so setting a listener for container resize, triggering redrawing of the chart will be necessary using this solution.

```
this.down('#chartContainer').add({
    xtype       : 'rallychart',
    chartConfig : {
        chart : {
            height : 500 //Set chart height here
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I have an app where a container's `height` and `width` are specified:

```
  var c2 = Ext.create('Ext.Container', {
        id:'c2',
        border: 5,
        style: {
            borderColor: 'red',
            borderStyle: 'solid'
        },
        height: 450,
        width:600
      });    
      this.add(c2);
```

and later a chart is added to that container with only `height` specified:

```
this.down('#c2').add(
        {
            xtype: 'rallychart',
            id: 'ch',
            height: 200,
            chartConfig: {
                chart:{
                  type: 'scatter',
                  zoomType: 'xy'
        },
  //....
```

and the chart fills both the width and height by default:

[image]

How is your example different?

Comment: When I set the 'height' attribute of the rallychart component, it's changing the outer containers height, not the chart itself. If I change the height to 200, as you have, only the top half of the chart is shown, as the bottom half is cut off by the container. If I change the height to 600, for example, the container will be 600px in height but the chart remains at 400px.

Comment: Hi Conner, I see the opposite outcome: the chart fills up the container by default, it's height having no effect on the container height. Let me know what I need to change to replicate what you see. My code is here: https://github.com/nmusaelian-rally/game-of-chicken-0

Comment: I loaded your code and saw the same results as in your example, but after changing the height attribute of both the container and chart, the height was still fixed at a max of 400px. Luckily, I was able to solve the issue on my own by changing the chart config before render. I'll add the answer for future devs who run into this issue.

Comment: so, outside of chartConfig the height is ignored. Thank you.